# How to modify Data Section of an exe(DD x000455)?

Tags: memory, patch-reversing

```
 005A45A6 > \83FE 50 CMP ESI,50 ; Switch (cases 0..50) 
 005A45A9 0F87 79150000 JA AcroByte.005A5B28 
 005A45AF . FF24B5 B6455A00 JMP DWORD PTR DS:[ESI*4+5A45B6]; AcroByte.005A46FA 
005A45B6 . FA465A00 DD AcroByte.005A46FA; Switch table used at 005A45AF 
 005A45BA . 51475A00 DD AcroByte.005A4751 
 005A45BE . 7C475A00 DD      AcroByte.005A477C 
 005A45C2 . 8B475A00 DD AcroByte.005A478B 
 005A45C6 . 9A475A00 DD AcroByte.005A479A 
 005A45CA . A9475A00 DD AcroByte.005A47A9 
 005A45CE . D4475A00 DD AcroByte.005A47D4 
 005A45D2 . ED475A00 DD AcroByte.005A47ED 
 005A45D6 . 06485A00 DD AcroByte.005A4806 
 005A45DA . 4B485A00 DD AcroByte.005A484B 
 005A45DE . E8485A00 DD AcroByte.005A48E8 
 005A45E2 . 3A495A00 DD AcroByte.005A493A 
 005A45E6 . 8E495A00 DD AcroByte.005A498E 
 005A45EA . 9A495A00 DD AcroByte.005A499A 
 005A45EE . E1495A00 DD AcroByte.005A49E1 
 005A45F2 . 174A5A00 DD AcroByte.005A4A17 
 005A45F6 . 594A5A00 DD AcroByte.005A4A59 
 005A45FA . A34A5A00 DD AcroByte.005A4AA3
```

I need help on the above code, the JUMP at address 005A45AF is associated with 005A46FA.
I want it to be associated to 005A4AA3.

My question is can I modify  DS:[ESI*4+5A45B6] to [ESI*4+5A4AA3] or the (4 between ESI and Address) also needs to be changed.

I really want to jump to 005A4AA3.

Please help it's memory not hardware I am patching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really want to jump to 005A4AA3.

Patch the bytes at virtual address `005A45AF` from `FF 24 B5 B6 45 5A 00` to `E9 EF 04 00 00 90 90`.

> My question is can I modify DS:[ESI*4+5A45B6] to [ESI*4+5A4AA3]

Yes, in which case you'd want to patch the bytes at virtual address `005A45AF` from `FF 24 B5 B6 45 5A 00` to `FF 24 B5 A3 4A 5A 00`.

Comment: I am sorry that I failed to mention this is a Case Switch Table from 0 to 50. So the JMP is currently using the Case 0. I wish I can make the JMP use Case 11.  So I have tried